# How do you find the sample mean when given the standard deviation and confidence interval?

Tags: probability, statistics

In 1988, a study followed 89 sedentary men for a year. 42 men were on a diet, and the remaining 47 were on an exercise routine. The group on the diet lost 7.2 kg on average, with a standard deviation of 3.9 kg. Construct a 99.7% confidence interval for the true average number of kg lost on diet.

From what we understand: 
We want to use the SD to find the variance and then use that to find the sample mean, but when we do that we got impossible numbers, so we couldn't identify p or n.

Does anyone know how we should start this?

Comment: "The group on the diet lost 7.2 kg on average ... ." Isn't that the sample mean?

Comment: I'm confused on what this question is asking

Comment: You certainly do appear to be confused. You are trying to answer a question that the exercise has already given you the answer to ("What is the sample mean?").

Answer (score 1):

> We want to use the SD to find the variance

You could do that, but I'm not sure it's helpful here....

> and then use that to find the sample mean

Not quite. Note that you're actually given the sample mean explicitly as a part of the problem text.

> but when we do that we got impossible numbers, so we couldn't identify p or n

I'm not sure what "$p$" you hope to identify, but this isn't a problem about a proportion; it's a problem about developing a confidence interval for a *mean*. Your task is to find the way that this has been done in your class (almost certainly either (a) with a certain table of numbers and a formula, or (b) with statistical software) and then to replicate that process.